# Static resources in GWT apps

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, war

Do you ever need to write your own HTML, CSS or JavaScript files for your GWT app? Any reason to ever write your own HTML/CSS and include it with the build? If so, under what circumstances, and where do you package it in the final WAR?

Comment: for the CSS part, https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideUiCss. Suck questions are covered by the GWT dev guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Some developers prefer to use an external CSS file for their app instead of a CSS resource. Then you add this CSS file to your /war directory, and provide a link to it in your host page  like you would do with any external CSS file.
2. If you use UI:Binder, which I highly recommend, you can write a lot of page or widgets' layouts in HTML as opposed to using GWT widgets. In this case you don't have to do anything with the HTML: GWT compiler will take care of it.
3. There is a way to use native JavaScript from inside the GWT app. Sometimes developers want a special effect or some functionality that they can't (or, quite often, don't know how to) implement in GWT. In this case you include the JavaScript code directly into your GWT code, or you use an external JavaScript file and reference it from GWT. In the latter case you include your JavaScript file in your /war directory and load it in your host page like with any JavaScript file.